# AI Milestones: Do we have Bots asking questions and semi-getting away with it?

Tags: discussion

This topic has an entirely different dimension than on any other online forum I can think of, and so should be regarded not as a purely negative prospect (informal Turing testing and so forth.)

I'm not saying that we have bots semi-passing, but I do see a high percentage of the questions on the stack, and I have been seeing questions that *could have* been asked by a bot.

These questions tend to be flagged for low quality, which is accurate from if asked by a human.  If asked by a bot though, they're not bad--cogent and fewer and fewer grammatical errors.